# Practice to return itself instead void in Java

Tags: java, coding-style

My team mates introduce me to new practice writing method which will not return void.

```
public class Test {
   public Test doCalculations() {
      //code
      return this;
   }
   public Test appendTitle(String test) {
      //code
      return this;
   }
}
```

Instead of returning void they suggest to return object itself. One of the advantage of this aproach they say, you can chain methods.

Instead of writing:

```
 while(1) {
    test.appendTitle("aaa");
    test.doCalculations();
    map.add(test);
 }
```

You can write more elegant code:

```
 while(1) {
     map.add(test.appendTitle("aaa").doCalculations());
 }
```

What could be disadvantages of this aproach? Do you suggest to include it in daily use?

Comment: I suggest you look into decorator design pattern. Of course you should think when to apply it.

Comment: Called _fluent interface_ (but not exclusively). I would suggest a line break before every `.`.

Comment: In my defense I didn't find this question: "Benefits..", also the question is askes so enigmaticly, I don't think many people will understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is not a good practice. By looking at the method signature that returns an object, how can I know if it is a entirely new instance that is being returned or the existing one being returned.Note that in cases of immutable classes modified methods do return a new 
instance of the class.

Comment: If the class is called `Builder` or something similar instead, it is fairly clear IMO.

Comment: True but this question seems to be more general than that

Comment: It is not a bad practice, in fact it is used for many configuration objects, builder objects, and, hell, should be used anywhere where setters can be invoked more than 1-2 times. Should be pretty obvious that it returns itself and not a new instance, otherwise, javadoc should clearly state so. Examples that use that pattern: Hibernate Criteria, Astyanax, Cloudera's hadoop config, and many more. Surely their developers know a thing or two about developing apis, so in my opinion the accepted answer is totally wrong.